# Controlling Hyper-V VM instance, and copying file to host OS

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

In code, preferably Java or C#, how might one:

1. Launch a Hyper-V VM, retain a handle to it
2. At an arbitrary point later on, copy a file from the VM to the host operating system
3. Close the VM/Release the memory

One idea I had was to use a web app running on local host to transfer the file, but I'm finding the VM is unable to connect to the localhost from the host OS, so I guess this idea is out the window?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have done something like that with the help of a tiny linux live VM.  It was bit complex because you have to dig out many things like sharing the vhd with the live VM, the live VM can be only of linux flavor to make it lightweight etc.

Just think if you can get some idea out of this !

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty in depth. As this engineering work isn't the meat of the project, it would need to be quite simple to implement. It seems it might not be feasible to do easily. Thanks for the insight :)